# Latex Binomial tree (space and overlapping)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I encounter the following problem: I want to fit a (vertical) binomial tree but the siblings from the third level overlap (no matter how I adjust the distances they either overlap with each other or they cross their cousins). What solution would you suggest? I've tried footnotesize font but it is not enough and I would like to keep the normal size. I thought maybe the children from parents $b_1 b_2$ and $b_2E[b_2]$ could be placed in the lower next Level but I don't know how to do that :( Thanks a lot for your kind help!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,reqno,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
baseline,
 level distance=20mm,
text depth=.1em,
text height=.8em,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=20em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=10em},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=20mm}]


\node   (z){$b$}
child {node (a) {$b_1$}
child {node  (b) {$b_1 \, b_1$}
child {node {$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_1$}
} 
child {node {$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_2$}}
}
child {node (g) {$b_1 \, b_2$}
  child {node {$b_1b_2E[b_1]$}}
  child {node {$b_1b_2E[b_2]$}}
}
}
 child {node  (j) {$b_2$}
child {node  (k) {$b_2 \, E[b_1]$}
  child {node {$b_2 E[b_1b_1]$}}
  child {node {$b_2 E[b_1b_2]$}}
}
child {node  (l) {$b_2 \, E[b_2]$}
child {node {$b_2E[b_2]E[b_1]$}}
child {node (c){$b_2E[b_2]E[b_2]$}    
 }
 }
};
\path (a) -- (j) ;
\path (b) -- (g) ;
\path (k) -- (l) ;
\path (k) -- (g) ;
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please complete your code to provide a complete, small document demonstrating your issue. It is very difficult to answer when we don't know the paper size, the font family or the font size! However, `forest` is very good at setting compact trees nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the trees to use `12pt` font means they take more space than default. (Standard classes default to `10pt`. `standalone`, which is often used to create graphics, defaults to `11pt`.)

Here is a `forest` version with no adjustments:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    [{$b$}, name=z
      [{$b_1$}, name=a
        [{$b_1 \, b_1$}, name=b
          [{$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_1$}
          ]
          [{$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_2$}
          ]
        ]
        [{$b_1 \, b_2$}, name=g
          [{$b_1b_2E[b_1]$}
          ]
          [{$b_1b_2E[b_2]$}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [{$b_2$}, name=j
        [{$b_2 \, E[b_1]$}, name=k
          [{$b_2 E[b_1b_1]$}
          ]
          [{$b_2 E[b_1b_2]$}
          ]
        ]
        [{$b_2 \, E[b_2]$}, name=l
          [{$b_2E[b_2]E[b_1]$}
          ]
          [{$b_2E[b_2]E[b_2]$}, name=c
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \path (a) -- (j) ;
    \path (b) -- (g) ;
    \path (k) -- (l) ;
    \path (k) -- (g) ;
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest version]

At 172x42mm, this fits within A4 but not at all comfortably unless you rotate the tree.

So let's try a version which incorporates your suggested change:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    [{$b$}, name=z
      [{$b_1$}, name=a
        [{$b_1 \, b_1$}, name=b
          [{$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_1$}
          ]
          [{$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_2$}
          ]
        ]
        [{$b_1 \, b_2$}, name=g, for children={l+=2\baselineskip}
          [{$b_1b_2E[b_1]$}
          ]
          [{$b_1b_2E[b_2]$}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [{$b_2$}, name=j
        [{$b_2 \, E[b_1]$}, name=k
          [{$b_2 E[b_1b_1]$}
          ]
          [{$b_2 E[b_1b_2]$}
          ]
        ]
        [{$b_2 \, E[b_2]$}, name=l, for children={l+=2\baselineskip}
          [{$b_2E[b_2]E[b_1]$}
          ]
          [{$b_2E[b_2]E[b_2]$}, name=c
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \path (a) -- (j) ;
    \path (b) -- (g) ;
    \path (k) -- (l) ;
    \path (k) -- (g) ;
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted tree]

The adjusted tree measures 131x52mm which is well within A4.

Comment: The last looks and fits perfectly! This was of huge help. I really struggle With Latex when it's not just mathematical expressions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

What about using a package that is dedicated to drawing trees such as these? If you're open to this, there are two main such packages: `forest` and `tikz-qtree`, both of which are built on top of TikZ.

Here is your tree using the `forest` package. The `tikz-qtree` package uses a similar syntax, but, as @cfr mentioned in a comment, `forest` is better at making trees more compact and handling spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
% This style is defined on page 8 of the current forest manual
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}}
}

\begin{document}  

\begin{forest} baseline, sn edges
[$b$
    [$b_{1}$
        [{$b_1 \, b_1$}
            [{$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_1$}]
            [{$b_1 \, b_1 \, b_2$}]
        ]
        [{$b_1 \, b_2$}
            [{$b_1b_2E[b_1]$}]
            [{$b_1b_2E[b_2]$}]
        ]
    ]
    [$b_{2}$
        [{$b_2 \, E[b_1]$}
            [{$b_2 E[b_1b_1]$}]
            [{$b_2 E[b_1b_2]$}]
        ]
        [{$b_1b_2E[b_2]$}
            [{$b_2E[b_2]E[b_1]$}]
            [{$b_2E[b_2]E[b_2]$}]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok! I didn't know about this package. The code seems also simpler. The only problem is that the tree gets out of the text. Is there a way to "justify" the tree? In the worst case one can add a fourth level. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @mark The tree is too big to fit within LaTeX's default margins. You can make the textsize smaller or you can put the entire `forest` environment inside of a `\scalebox` to get it to fit within LaTeX's default margins. Based on my experimentation, a `\scalebox` factor of `0.75` will fit within LaTeX's default margins.